# phpinfo doesn't work on some php files on the same directory

Tags: php, mamp

This is making me confused, two php files (say `a.php` and `b.php`) on the same directory running `phpinfo` and some `echo`. `a.php` is running them perfectly, and the other just doesn't run them.

For that one (`b.php`), it doesn't have any headers: `header()`, nor special functions. Just some `sql` queries, etc.

Also, the following script runs correctly on `a.php`:

```
include_once('../wp-config.php');

$sel = "SELECT * FROM wp_transaction WHERE customer_id =1 AND createddate BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND SYSDATE()";
$res = mysql_query($sel);
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);
echo "Count result:".$num;//it shows 18, by checking on the DB table, that's correct
```

However, in `b.php`, that same snippet of code doesn't print the `echo` output at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe there's something else right before/after that code section that causes the issue. Without seeing the code it's hard to tell. Also, with 2000+ rep you should know better than using `mysql_*` functions!

Comment: It's a previous developer code I am fixing it. I don't want to migrate all the file to PDO because it will result in lot of changes.

Comment: Start by fixing this section, if you'll do it, little by little, eventually the code will be fixed (and secured!). Further, if cc112358 is correct, it might fix your problem as well ;)

Comment: and create new file with the same name, replace the old one, and all works fine now. I don't know how to explain the root cause which prevent old file from executing correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free the result. Once you have executed the query and obtained the result it may be active in memory. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php